# Result discrepency in PyMC implementations of the M&M

Tags: python-2.7, bayesian, pymc

A PyMC solution to the M&M problem is shown in this link:
http://dataorigami.net/blogs/napkin-folding/29036419-bayesian-m-m-problem-in-pymc-2

In an attempt to solve the problem in a slightly different fashion I used the following method:

```
import pymc as pm


p = [
 #brown, yellow, red, green, orange, tan, blue
 [.3, .2, .2, .1, .1, .1, .0], # 1994 bag
 [.13, .14, .13, .2, .16, .0, .24]  # 1996 bag
]

theta = pm.DiscreteUniform('theta', lower=0, upper=1)

@pm.deterministic
def first_bag_selection(p=p, theta=theta):
    return p[theta]

@pm.deterministic
def second_bag_selection(p=p, theta=theta):
    return p[1-theta]

first_bag = pm.Categorical('first_bag', first_bag_selection, value=1, observed=True)
second_bag = pm.Categorical('second_bag', second_bag_selection, value=3, observed=True)

model = pm.MCMC([p, theta, first_bag_selection, second_bag_selection, first_bag, second_bag])
model.sample(10000, 1000, 10)
model.summary()
pm.Matplot.plot(model)
```

However, after training the average of 'theta' becomes 0.416, i.e., 
print(model.trace('theta')[:].mean())
0.416333333333

This is while the solution from the link suggests a different answer to posterior probability of choosing the old bag. Could you please comment?